# WP Update post to again update the current posr

Tags: wordpress

I have a post type called `pdf files` with a custom metabox `pdf fic` /

When I save post I want to update current post title with the pdf path.

### My function use the hook save post :

```
function set_private_categories($post_id) {

if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post->ID ) ) 
    $post_id = $parent_id;


    remove_action( 'save_post', 'set_private_categories' );

    $fic = get_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-fichier-pdf', true);
    
    wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_id,'post_title'=>$fic, 'post_status' => 'private' ) );

    add_action( 'save_post', 'set_private_categories' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_private_categories' );
```

My problem :

I have to update twice before the title is replaced by the pdf metabox input value, it seems that wordpress does not update the database with the new value of the metabox.

How to achieve this please? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $POST['wpcf-fichier-pdf'] to grab the meta value before the post is saved. Make sure to sanitize the value before saving to the database.